# JQuery: How to parsing XML to know whether there is an element within the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

For this code:

```
$(this).find("Name")
```

This is XML (element "Name"):

```
  <Win32_Processor>
    <AddressWidth>32</AddressWidth>
    <L2CacheSize>256</L2CacheSize>
    <L2CacheSpeed>600</L2CacheSpeed>
    <LastErrorCode/>
    <Level>6</Level>
    <LoadPercentage>1</LoadPercentage>
    <Manufacturer>GenuineIntel</Manufacturer>
    <MaxClockSpeed>598</MaxClockSpeed>
    <Name></Name>
    <VoltageCaps/>
  </Win32_Processor>
```

Comment: please post your xml its very hard to guess...

Comment: Please include your question in the post as well as just the title.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length property of the above;  if it is > 0, then at least one element was found.

Comment: It is work for this situation? There are no nested elements. This is the last level.
`<Name></Name>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  If you are searching a single XML element called "Name", then it contains no elements called "name_element".  So searching it with find would return a length of zero.

Comment: In that case, if $(this) is the "Name" element, you will get a length of zero, because the "Name" element does not contain an element of "Name".  If $(this) refers to the entire XML, then you should get a length of 1.